# helm overriding sub chart template in the base chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have my app chart (A) that depends on some generic chart (B)

I need from my app chart (A) to override the deployment template of the sub chart (B)

I tried to copy and paste from sub chat to the parent chart and do the modifications like the following:

```
A/
├── Chart.yaml
├── charts
│   └── B-1.0.0.tgz
├── templates
│   └── deployment.yaml
└── values.yaml
```

but It ends in duplicate deployments, one with the original structure (from B), and one with the modified one (in A).

I've read [Charts and Global values](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/) but cannot find a way to solve the issue.

Comment: I don't think that you can override the deployment, unless it is extensible, meaning that subchart exposes values that can be overridden in your base chart.

Comment: no, it isn't.... the sub-chart is not overridable in this case.

I need to add support for a list of config maps, but the sub-chart only allows one config map

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answer will fit your request, but I found that my subchart uses image generated using template defined in it's `_helpers.yaml` file.
This template can be simple overrided using `_helpers.yaml` file of parent chart.

Just create a new template with the same name.

For example, subchart has `charts/mysubchart/templates/_helpers.yaml`:

```
{{- define "mysubchart.image" -}}
  {{- printf "%s:%s" .Values.image.repository .Values.image.tag -}}
{{- end }}
```

You can create `templates/_helpers.yaml`:

```
{{- define "mysubchart.image" -}}
  {{- .Values.global.someCustomValue}}
{{- end }}
```

Thus deploying chart with `--set global.someCustomValue=alpine@sha256:eece025e432126ce23f223450a0326fbebde39cdf496a85d8c016293fc851978`

Will override default image in subchart